# How to check if an ArgumentError is raised?

Tags: ruby, exception

I would like to be able to check to see if a certain line of code generates an `ArgumentError`.

Something like:

```
if this.ArgumentError?
  puts "there was an error"
else 
  puts "no error"
end
```

I have searched the documentation and haven't found anything that seems to work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the exception handling mechanism. For example:

```
begin
  # here is the code that could raise ArgumentError   
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "there was an error"
else
  puts "no error"
end
```

Refer to the [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html) for more information about how to handle and raise exceptions.